# Apache Site Aliases & WordPress Multisite

Tags: multisite, apache

I'm attempting to allow users to access the same multisite content on a sub-site by using both `www.example.com` as well as `www.example.org`.

Upon initial setup, I simply redirected all allowed hosts / server aliases (e.g. `www.example.org`) to the Server Name entry (e.g. `www.example.com`). This worked fine for the last few months.

However, I was recently approached by the client who is requesting the requested domain remain in the browser's address bar (a simple redirect from an Apache no longer fulfills client requirements). They are in the non-profit sector and the `.org` extension is important to them.

With single-site setups, I'd usually use `update_option('siteUrl', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])` to achieve this functionality. However, with a multisite, my research suggests that those hooks do not work the same way.

What is the secret to doing this? I find it hard to believe we can't have a similar functionality in the multisite world.

Comment: Sounds like SEO suicide. Duplicate content. Just don't do that. Instead simply redirect all your traffic to the *.org URL and update WordPress' site_url accordingly.

Comment: Agreed with @leymannx don't have the same content on both URLs, unless you really know how to [setup canonical link rel](https://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-rel-canonical-seo-value-cross-posted-content) URLs. Setup a 301 redirect from one TLD to the other